# React Native: How do I display a variable in a Text element once an async function has returned it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, fetch, expo

The `fetch` function returns all the correct info; I know this because it all gets logged to the console, but the `Text` element never shows the pokemon name once the json data is saved into the Pokemon class. Im using expo btw.

```js
export default function App() {
  let Pokemon = {
    getInfo: async (name) => {
      name = name.toLowerCase();

      const uri = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`;
      
      await fetch(uri)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        Pokemon.name = data.forms[0].name;
        Pokemon.img = data.sprites.front_default;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if(error){
          console.log(`Failed to find "${name}"`)
        }
      });

      console.log(await Pokemon.name, await Pokemon.img)
    }
  }

  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Enter A Pokemon');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text style={styles.title}>{Pokemon.name}</Text>

      <TextInput
      style={styles.textBox}
      clearTextOnFocus={true}
      onChangeText={async text => {
        onChangeText(text)
        Pokemon.getInfo(text)
      }}
      value={value}
      />

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call me cap'n hook:

```js
export default function App() {
  let Pokemon = {
    getInfo: async (name) => {
      name = name.toLowerCase();

      const uri = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`;
      
      await fetch(uri)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        Pokemon.name = data.forms[0].name;
        Pokemon.img = data.sprites.front_default;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if(error){
          console.log(`Failed to find "${name}"`)
        }
      });

      console.log(await Pokemon.name, await Pokemon.img)
    }
  }

  

  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Enter A Pokemon');
  const [myText, setMyText] = React.useState("My Original Text");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text style={styles.title}>{myText}</Text>

      <TextInput
      style={styles.textBox}
      clearTextOnFocus={true}
      onChangeText={async text => {
        onChangeText(text)
        await Pokemon.getInfo(text)
        setMyText(await Pokemon.name)
      }}
      value={value}
      />

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```